# Netlogo one-to-one relation

Tags: netlogo

I have a netlogo problem for which I can't seem to find a solution, but yet it feels very basic. 
I have two types of breeds:

```
breed [individuals individual]
breed [cars car]
```

I want to create a link from one individual to one car. So, its a one-one relation. I use this code to do that:

```
to setup-individuals
  create-individuals individuals-number [
    set ID 2
    set shape "person"
    set color yellow
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set activity ""
    set activity_time 0
    let rand random 2
    ifelse rand = 0
    [
      set owns-car false
      ]
    [
      set owns-car true
      create-link-to one-of cars ;; here is the issue
      ]
    ]
end
```

The problem is that if i use "`create-link-to one-of cars`" there are more than one individuals linked to one car, but I want each individual to have a distinct car. When trying the following command: "`create-link-to one-of cars with [my-in-links = 0]`" its giving me the following ERROR: "CREATE-LINK-TO expected input to be a turtle but got NOBODY instead." I tried many variations of this command, but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempted solution of `create-link-to one-of cars with [my-in-links = 0]` is on the correct path. However, if you look at the NetLogo dictionary, you will see that `my-in-links` returns an agentset, not an integer giving the number of members of that agentset. So you need to compare to empty rather than compare to the number 0.

This is the code that is syntactically closest to what you have: `create-link-to one-of cars with [count my-in-links = 0]`.

What you really want though is something more like `create-link-to one-of cars with [not any? my-in-links]`

Comment: create-link-to one-of cars with [not any? my-in-links] 
did the work
thnx mate

Comment: `my-in-links = nobody` wouldn't work — `nobody` is not equal to an empty agentset. the `not any?...` solution is also what I would have suggested.